# Custom Directive, requires some condition before kick-in the required field

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and still learning.

I'm trying to create a custom directive and I would like to have some conditions where requires some conditions before the customrequired kick-in. For example checkbox is ticked. Below is my sample directive and HTML. Thanks and really appreciate your response. Please let me know if you still need some information.

```
.directive('customrequired', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            //conditional approach like, requires checkbox to be checked.?

        }
    };
})
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Create.ProductName" name="ProductName" customrequired="Create.IsRequired == 1"/>
<input type="checbox" ng-model="Create.IsRequired" name="Required" />
```

Comment: If it's just simple condition like checkbox then it makes sense to use ngRequired directive for this.

Comment: would you mind to explain what is the condition?

Comment: @PankajParkar, the condition is. if the checkbox is checked it will trigger the validation when you submit the form or when out of focus.

Comment: Then you could achieve this using `ng-required="expression"` as @dsfq suggested

Comment: we have a custom error summary validation and if I used the ng-required="expression" the error message is not displaying.. but the validation in ngRequired kick-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do put watch on your directive value and put your logic in only if its true.

```
.directive('customrequired', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {

              scope.$watch(attr.customrequired,function(value){
              if(value){
                 //conditional approach like, requires checkbox to be checked.?
                 }  
             })

        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Hi @srjt, could you give me an example logic on the conditional area? no idea yet on that

Comment: inside if statement you can attach event listener to onblur for element and then perform your validation there. If value is not true then remove the listener.